# Create an select option with selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I have 2 selects for setting the expiration date on a credit card and I want to test that the error messaging comes back correctly when the card is expired.  The only problem I have is that right now I can't pick a value that's expired since the list starts at Jan 2011 which isn't expired yet.  What I'm thinking about doing is using javascript in selenium to inject a known expired value.  Anyone have any idea on how to do this or suggestions on a better way to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `storeEval` method to run snippets of JavaScript using Selenium. The JavaScript is run in the context of the Selenium object so you need `window.document` to get the document reference (hence the reason for the first line).

This snippet is the JavaScript for adding a new option the `select` element:

```
var d = window.document;
var select = d.getElementsByName("selectName")[0];
var option = d.createElement('option');
option.value='Value';
option.innerHTML='My new option';
select.appendChild(option);
```

Here's the copy/paste of my Selenium IDE entry for you.

```
<tr>
 <td>storeEval</td>
 <td>var d = window.document;var select = d.getElementsByName(&quot;selectName&quot;)[0];var option = d.createElement('option');option.value='Value';option.innerHTML='My new option';select.appendChild(option);</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can just have the standard `select` method in Selenium to select the option. Of course, you can always do `option.setAttribute('selected',true)` in the JavaScript snippet but having Selenium do it will ensure the new value has been selected (since it will fail if it can't find it).

Comment: I got it working using runScript rather than storeEval like so ele = document.getElementById('expYear');ele.options[ele.options.length] = new Option('2005','2005');ele.selectedIndex = ele.options.length -1

Answer (score 0):

```
    storeEval
    window.document.getElementsByName('descript')[0].value;
    element
```